# Получение данных из SphinxQL запроса "call keywords"

Tags: sphinx

Появилась необходимость извлекать normalized значение от ключевого слова. Существует ли способ получить данные из такого запроса?

```
sphinxQL> call keywords('Растение','index_name', 1);
+------+------------------+--------------+------+-------+
| qpos | tokenized        | normalized   | docs | hits  |
+------+------------------+--------------+------+-------+
| 1    | растение         | растен       | 9033 | 19758 |
+------+------------------+--------------+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

Я думаю, что это должно быть что-то похожее

```
select * FROM (call keywords('растение','index_name', 1))`
```

Но такой вариант не работает.

Буду благодарен за помощь в решении проблемы.

Comment: Не понял вопроса, чем простой и рабочий `call keywords` не устроил и зачем тут select?

Comment: Необходимо в приложении получить эти данные. Иными словами как call результат получить в приложении.

Comment: Точно так же как и в обычном select, только вместо select пишите call keywords. Если это по каким-то причинам не получается, то опишите проблему с вашим приложением

Answer (score 0):

> Существует ли способ получить данные из такого запроса?

Средствами SphinxQL - нет.

1. Для `CALL KEYWORDS` нет опции, чтоб получать только колонку normalized
2. `CALL KEYWORDS` не поддерживается в sub-select'ах
3. Через `SET @@var` тоже не получится
   Для этого нет поддержки ни в Sphinx 2/3, ни в Manticore до 3.5.3

Средствами приложения - легко, потому что не смотря на то, что команда называется `CALL KEYWORDS`, а не `SELECT` возвращает она точно то же самое, что и любой `SELECT`, а именно строки с несколькими значениями в каждой. Следовательно извлекать значение normalized можно в самом приложении.

Comment: Я пробовал выборку, но она не работает. Если я просто выбираю данные обычного запроса типа SELECT примерно так $result = mysqli_query($sphinxConnect, 'SELECT item_id, module, item FROM indexName WHERE MATCH('арбуз');'); то строки данных успешно возвращаются запросом, но не запросы вида "call keywords('арбуз','indexName');"

Comment: @yuriyant опишите в тексте вопроса, что конкретно означает «она не работает»

Comment: mysqli_query возвращает false для запросов "call keywords('арбуз','indexName');"

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за ответы, в результате найти решение как извлекать данные на php так и не удалось, но я перевел эту часть приложения на nodejs стек и проблема с получением данных запросов CALL решилась сама собой.